# No me funciona el responsive de Boostrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

espero que estén bien.

Tengo un problema desde hace un rato que no he podido solucionar. Nunca me había pasado y ahora no sé o no encuentro el error, por lo que acudo a ustedes para solicitar su ayuda para encontrar el error que hay en el código

Estoy usando un navbar de Boostrap, pero resulta que cuando la pantalla se hace pequeña y sale el responsive, doy click a las tres líneas en donde se contrae las opciones del nav y este no abre. ¿Alguno sabe qué puede ser?

No sé qué puede ser y no me funciona. Revisé librerías pero no sé cuál sea el error.

Cuando doy click al [=] no me sale nada y debería de salir las opciones o links que hay en el navbar.

Gracias de antemano!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Conectando base de datos a mi pagina web</title>
  <!-- excel -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport@5.2.0/dist/css/tableexport.min.css">
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- DataTable -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <!-- font awesone -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-...tu-integridad-aquí..." crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/styles/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/styles/normalize.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Jquery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <!-- DataTable -->
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

  <!-- excel -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport@5.2.0/dist/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>

  <script src="./public/scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Toggler button del navbar no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477530/toggler-button-del-navbar-no-funciona)

Comment: Como te indica @padaleiana este es un error común, si actualizaste la librería de Bootstrap a la version 5, también debes actualizar los atributos data-*

Comment: Documentación oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

Esta importado varias versiones de Boostrap esto puede traerle conflictos.
la verson mas reciente que esta importando es la 5.2.2 de bootstrap por favor en la documentacion relacione la version de bootstrap mas alta que este usando y ahi encontrara los snippets de los componentes que desee usar.

en su codigo reemplaze el contenido del header por:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

si se da cuenta los atributos data incluyen bs "data-bs-{$othervalue}" esto permite que el js de bootstrap se ejecute correctamente.